# XSL Template is making loading speed very slow

Tags: javascript, xml, performance, xslt, xpath

Hello the below code is making my page loading speed very slow. Can you help please!

```
 <xsl:template match="Category" mode="CategorySelectorScript">
            <xsl:variable name="ThisCategoryID" select="CategoryID"/>
            <xsl:variable name="HasChildren"><xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="../Category[ParentCategoryID=$ThisCategoryID]">
                    true
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    false
                </xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            arrCategory=new Array(<xsl:value-of select="CategoryID"/>, <xsl:value-of select="ParentCategoryID"/>, '<xsl:value-of select="Name"/>', <xsl:value-of select="$HasChildren"/>);
            arrCategories.push(arrCategory);
        </xsl:template>
```

The problem is with this line `<xsl:when test="../Category[ParentCategoryID=$ThisCategoryID]">` When i remove `../` from the XPath it loads fast but then i didn't get the working feature. So is there any alternative of `../` which works ?

**Full Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"    
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">

<xsl:output method="xml" 
            omit-xml-declaration="yes"
            indent="yes"
            encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="Location">
        <xsl:call-template name="CategorySelectorScript"/>

        <form id="frmLocationCategoryAdd" action="locationcategoriesadd.php" method="post">
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" id="inpAction" name="inpAction" value="SAVE"/>
                <input type="hidden" id="inpLocationID" name="inpLocationID" value="{LocationID}"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="inpCategoryIDs" id="inpCategoryIDs" value=""/>
            </div>

            <div id="categoryselects"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></div>

            <div><a id="categoryselected" href="#" class="actionlink addcategory">Add this category</a></div>
            <div id="categoryalreadyselected">This category has already been selected</div>

            <h3 id="categoriestoadd">Categories to add</h3>
            <div id="categoriesselected"><p id="nocategoriesmessage">No categories</p></div>

            <div class="formcontrols">
                <a class="savelink" href="#" id="savelink">
                    <span>Add Categories</span>
                </a>
                <a class="cancellink" href="#" id="cancellink">
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="CategorySelectorScript">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <xsl:value-of select="$start_html_comment" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            $(document).ready(
            function()
            {
                $('#cancellink').click( function() {
                    $('#inpAction').val('CANCEL');
                    $('#frmLocationCategoryAdd').submit();
                    }
                );

                $('#savelink').click( function() {
                    ProcessCategoryIDs();

                    <!-- alert($('#inpCategoryIDs').val()); -->

                    $('#frmLocationCategoryAdd').submit();
                }
                );

                $('#categoryselects').append(CreateCategorySelectBox(<xsl:value-of select="/XML/RootCategoryID"/>));

                $('#categoryselected').hide();
                $('#categoryalreadyselected').hide();

                $('#categoryselected').click( function() {
                    $('#categoryselected').hide();
                    $('#nocategoriesmessage').hide();

                    intThisCategoryID=0;
                    strCategoryHierarchy='';
                    $('#categoryselects').children().each( function(i) {
                        if (!isNaN(parseInt(this.value, 10)))
                        {
                            intThisCategoryID=parseInt(this.value, 10);
                            strCategoryHierarchy+=GetCategoryName(intThisCategoryID)+' <xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/> ';
                        }
                    }
                    );

                    <!-- alert(intThisCategoryID); -->

                    <!-- remove last > -->
                    strCategoryHierarchy=strCategoryHierarchy.replace(/ <xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/> $/i, '');

                    strCategoryToAdd='<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>div id="AddedCategory_'+intThisCategoryID+'" class="addedcategory"<xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>';

                    strCategoryToAdd+='<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>span class="addedcategoryhierarchy"<xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>'+strCategoryHierarchy+'<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>/span<xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>';

                    strCategoryToAdd+='<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>a id="DeleteCategory_'+intThisCategoryID+'" class="actionlink deletecategory" onclick="DeleteCategory(this)"<xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>Delete this category<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>/a<xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>';

                    strCategoryToAdd+='<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>/div<xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>';

                    $('#categoriesselected').append(strCategoryToAdd);

                    return false;   
                }
                );

            }
            )

            function DeleteCategory(oDeleteClicked)
            {
                $('#AddedCategory_'+getID(oDeleteClicked.id)).remove();

                if (0==$('.addedcategory').length)
                    $('#nocategoriesmessage').show();
            }

            function GetCategoryName(intCategoryID)
            {
                for (i=0; i<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>arrCategories.length; i++)
                {
                    if (arrCategories[i][0]==intCategoryID)
                        return arrCategories[i][2];
                }

                return '';
            }

            function SelectClicked(oSelect)
            {           
                intCategoryID=$('#'+oSelect.id).val();
                intParentCategoryID=getID(oSelect.id);
                strCategoryText=$('#CategoryID_'+intParentCategoryID+'_'+intCategoryID).html();
                CategoryClicked(intCategoryID, intParentCategoryID, strCategoryText);
            }

            function CategoryClicked(intCategoryID, intParentCategoryID, strCategoryText)
            {
                    <!--
                    alert('intCategoryID: '+intCategoryID);
                    alert('intParentCategoryID: '+intParentCategoryID);
                    -->

                    $('#categoryselected').hide();
                    $('#categoryalreadyselected').hide();
                    <!-- some pretty gnarly stuff to get all sibling select boxes after the current one -->
                    var allSelects = $('#categoryselects select');
                    var currentIndex = allSelects.index($('#CategorySelect_'+intParentCategoryID)[0]);
                    var nextSiblings = allSelects.gt(currentIndex);
                    nextSiblings.remove();

                    <!-- if this isn't a leaf category, populate the next select box with its children -->
                    if (-1!=strCategoryText.search('&gt;') || -1!=strCategoryText.search('<xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>')) <!-- for some reason safari sees the non-escaped > in the string -->
                    {
                        $('#categoryselects').append(CreateCategorySelectBox(intCategoryID));
                        $('#CategorySelect_'+intCategoryID).focus();

                        /* force scrolling div over to the right */
                        oCategorySelects=document.getElementById('categoryselects');
                        oCategorySelects.scrollLeft=oCategorySelects.scrollWidth-680;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /* check that this category isn't already in the selected categories */
                        var bFound=false;

                        $('#categoriesselected').children().each( function() {
                            if (getID(this.id)==intCategoryID)
                                bFound=true;
                        }
                        );

                        if (bFound)
                            $('#categoryalreadyselected').show();
                        else
                            $('#categoryselected').show();
                    }
            }

            function ProcessCategoryIDs()
            {
                arrCategoryIDs=new Array();

                $('#categoriesselected').children().each( function() {
                    if (!isNaN(parseInt(getID(this.id), 10)))
                        arrCategoryIDs.push(getID(this.id));
                }
                );

                $('#inpCategoryIDs').val(arrCategoryIDs.join());
            }

            <!-- generate javascript array from the categories XML: -->
            var arrCategories=new Array();

            <xsl:apply-templates select="/XML/Categories/Category" mode="CategorySelectorScript"/>

            <!-- alert(dump(arrCategories)); -->

            <!-- category select box writing stuff -->
            function CreateCategorySelectBox(intCategoryID)
            {
                strSelectBox='<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>select id="CategorySelect_'+intCategoryID+'" size="10" onclick="SelectClicked(this)"<xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>';

                arrCategoriesInThisCategory=GetCategoriesWithParentID(intCategoryID);

                for (i=0; i<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>arrCategoriesInThisCategory.length; i++)
                {
                    if (true==arrCategoriesInThisCategory[i][3])
                        strChildMarker=' <xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>';
                    else
                        strChildMarker='';

                    strSelectBox+='<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>option id="CategoryID_'+intCategoryID+'_'+arrCategoriesInThisCategory[i][0]+'" value="'+arrCategoriesInThisCategory[i][0]+'"<xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>'+arrCategoriesInThisCategory[i][2]+strChildMarker+'<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>/option<xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>';
                }

                strSelectBox+='<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>/select<xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>';

                return strSelectBox;
            }

            function GetCategoriesWithParentID(intParentCategoryID)
            {
                arrResult=new Array();
                for (i=0; i<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>arrCategories.length; i++)
                {
                    if (arrCategories[i][1]==intParentCategoryID)
                        arrResult.push(arrCategories[i]);
                }

                return arrResult;
            }
        // <xsl:value-of select="$end_html_comment" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </script>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Category" mode="CategorySelectorScript">
        <xsl:variable name="ThisCategoryID" select="CategoryID"/>
        <xsl:variable name="HasChildren"><xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="../Category[ParentCategoryID=$ThisCategoryID]">
                true
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                false
            </xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        arrCategory=new Array(<xsl:value-of select="CategoryID"/>, <xsl:value-of select="ParentCategoryID"/>, '<xsl:value-of select="Name"/>', <xsl:value-of select="$HasChildren"/>);
        arrCategories.push(arrCategory);
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- category filter for location searches (front and back end ) -->
    <xsl:template name="CategoryFilter">
        <xsl:param name="FiltersOpen">0</xsl:param>

        <input type="hidden" name="inpCategoryIDs" id="inpCategoryIDs" value="0"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="0 = $FiltersOpen">
                <a href="#" id="filterlink">Filter by location categories</a>
                <a href="#" id="cancelfilterlink" style="display:none">Remove location category filters</a>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <a href="#" id="filterlink" style="display:none">Filter by location categories</a>
                <a href="#" id="cancelfilterlink">Remove location category filters</a>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

        <div id="categoryfilters">
            <xsl:if test="0 = $FiltersOpen">
                <xsl:attribute name="style">display:none;</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <div id="categoryselects"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></div>

            <a id="categoryselected" href="#" class="actionlink addcategory">Add this category</a>
            <div id="categoryalreadyselected">This category has already been selected</div>

            <h3 id="categoriestoadd">Categories to filter by</h3>
            <div id="categoriesselected"><p id="nocategoriesmessage">No categories</p></div>
        </div> <!-- #categoryfilters -->

        <script type="text/javascript">
        <xsl:value-of select="$start_html_comment" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            $(document).ready(
                function()
                {
                    $('#filterlink').click( function () {
                        $('#categoryfilters').slideDown();
                        $(this).hide();
                        $('#cancelfilterlink').show();
                        return false;
                    }
                    );

                    $('#cancelfilterlink').click( function() {
                        $('#categoryfilters').slideUp();

                        $('#categoryfilters select:gt(0)').remove();
                        $('#categoryfilters select:first option[@selected]').removeAttr('selected');

                        $('#categoriesselected').children().remove();
                        $('#categoriesselected').append('<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>p id="nocategoriesmessage"<xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>No categories<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>/p<xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>')

                        $(this).hide();
                        $('#filterlink').show();

                        return false;
                    }
                    );

                    if (0!=arrSelectedCategoryIDs.length)
                    {
                        $('#nocategoriesmessage').hide();
                        $('#categoryfilters').show();
                        $('#filterlink').hide();
                        $('#cancelfilterlink').show();

                        for (i=0; i<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>arrSelectedCategoryIDs.length; i++)
                        {
                            SelectCategory(arrSelectedCategoryIDs[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            );

            function SelectCategory(intCategoryID)
            {
                strCategoryToAdd='<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>div id="AddedCategory_'+intCategoryID+'" class="addedcategory"<xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>';

                strCategoryToAdd+='<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>span class="addedcategoryhierarchy"<xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>'+CategoryHierarchyString(intCategoryID)+'<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>/span<xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>';

                strCategoryToAdd+='<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>a id="DeleteCategory_'+intCategoryID+'" class="actionlink deletecategory" onclick="DeleteCategory(this)"<xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>Delete this category<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>/a<xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>';

                strCategoryToAdd+='<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>/div<xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>';

                $('#categoriesselected').append(strCategoryToAdd);
            }

            function CategoryHierarchyString(intCategoryID)
            {
                var strTemp='';
                var i=0;

                for (i=0; i<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>arrCategories.length; i++)
                {
                    if (arrCategories[i][0]==intCategoryID)
                    {
                        if (<xsl:value-of select="/XML/RootCategoryID"/>==arrCategories[i][1])
                        {
                            return arrCategories[i][2];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            strTemp=arrCategories[i][2];
                            return CategoryHierarchyString(arrCategories[i][1])+' <xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/> '+strTemp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        // <xsl:value-of select="$end_html_comment" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </script>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

PS: If anything else is need please comment i will share the requirements with you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown the source XML.

If the number of Category elements is large and if they are all at the same level in the document, then you should get an improvement by defining a key:

```
<xsl:key name="CategoryByParentCategory" match="Category"
     use="ParentCategoryID"/>
```

and then change your test from `test="../Category[ParentCategoryID=$ThisCategoryID]"` to `test="key('CategoryByParentCategory', $ThisCategoryID)"`

(This change isn't safe if the `Category` elements are nested or if you aren't searching all of them: that's why we need to see the XML)

A point about your logic: you are setting the value of the variable `$HasChildren` to a text node containing the string "true" or "false" surrounded by a load of whitespace, which you are then inserting into some generated Javascript. You could achieve the effect more conveniently by changing the variable declaration to

```
<xsl:variable name="HasChildren"
 select="boolean(key('CategoryByParentCategory', $ThisCategoryID))"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It just worked magically by adding the xsl:key above the template.

Comment: I'm curious about that restriction that it's not safe to use Key on nested elements... I've never seen that before, and can't find any further information about it. Any chance you can provide a link to documentation or more specifics? Thanks.

Comment: By "unsafe", I meant that the replacement code using key() would give different results from the original code in cases where Category elements were nested, so I couldn't guarantee that the substitution was correct in this case. There's no general problem with using keys on nested elements.